# Add a shape of native size

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, office-interop

So if you select an AutoShape (e.g. Ribbon > INSERT > Shapes > Pie) and then click once in the document without dragging, the shape will be instantiated at a predefined size. This predefined size is different for different shapes. For example, whereas the *native* size of **Pie** shape is 1 x 1, **Up-Down Arrow** is 1.33 x 0.53.

How can I insert a shape with this native size programmatically? The only way of inserting shapes that I have found is `Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 0, 0, 100, 100)`, which requires both width and height to be specified. Supplying 0 or -1 do not do what I want.